# 401 Error when creating file using SFTP Logic App Action

Tags: json, azure, workflow, sftp, azure-logic-apps

I am transferring 50 flat files smaller than 15mb each from blob Azure storage to an SFTP site using the create file SFTP action. When the App completes it does so without writing all the files to SFTP it only writes maybe 46 files. when checking the run details I see 401 Permission errors on the files that did not transfer in some cases it writes 0 bytes and does not fail consistently for the same files. So there are 2 concerns here 1 is how is possible to get a 401 error for only some files and 2 how to add additional code to retry the failed files or 0 byte files since doing a retry works.[Click here to see actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufaHw.png)